# Can I change one component State from another component?

Tags: reactjs

I know that in Java I would simply send the object itself, here I believe it's meant to be sent by a State.

All I want is to change the state of the contacts component using the addcontacts component.

```
contacts:
    
    

class Contacts extends Component {
      state = {
        contacts: [
          { id: 1, name: 'Doron', email: ***, phone: *** }],
      };
render() {
    return (
      <div className='contacts-container'>

        <Addcontacts Listofx={this.state.contacts} Data ={this.state}/>
        {
        this.state.contacts.map((contact) => {
          const { id, name, email, phone } = contact;
          return (
            
            <Contact
              key={id}
              id={id}
              name={name}
              email={email}
              phone={phone}
              onDelete={this.onDelete}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

I basically want to add another contact in the array of contacts array in the component "contacts" using addcontact.

Comment: This would normally be done by either passing a state modification function to the child component, or using a different state mechanism like a context, Redux, etc.

Comment: could you provide me with an example or a link that explain it XD

Comment: Any React tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you would do it with a functional component, you can apply similar logic to class components - pass parent functions to children and then call them from there:

```
    const Contacts = () => {
        [state, setState] = useState({
            contacts: [
              { id: 1, name: 'Doron', email: ***, phone: *** }],
        });
        const onDelete = (id) => {
           setState((prevState) => {
               newState = prevState.filter(contact => contact.id !== id);
               return [...newState];
           });
        }
       const addContact = (contact) => {
           setState((prevState) => {
               return [...prevState, contact];
           });
       }

        return (
          <div className='contacts-container'>
    
            <Addcontacts Listofx={state.contacts} Data ={state}/>
            {
            state.contacts.map((contact) => {
              const { id, name, email, phone } = contact;
              return (
                
                <Contact
                  key={id}
                  id={id}
                  name={name}
                  email={email}
                  phone={phone}
                  onDelete={() => onDelete(id)}
                  addContact={addContact}
                />
              );
            })}
          </div>
        );
      }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can and there are multiple ways. Jozef's answer here told you one way to do it which is only applies if you want to change parent state from child state. if you also want to change child state from parent state you have to learn state management properly. To achieve this goal you can use [React Context Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) etc.